# SharePoint Diagnostic logging VS usage data collection

Tags: logging, diagnostics, log, wss-logging

I was reading about SharePoint diagnostic logging and the difference between the usage data collection, and I am confused about why the usage data collection logs info in 2 separate places, one in the SharePoint logs, and the other in the database? Is this information in 2 places the same? If yes, why the duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically this is how it works.

- SharePoint writes the Usage data into Usage Logs.
- SharePoint Timer(Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data
  Processing,) Job move that data into Usage Database for later use.

Once the data in the database then you can run the run/view reports in SharePoint.

This is the data about usage on SharePoint Farm, like Page requests, feature use, search query latency, etc. This data is similar to IIS log, however unlike IIS logs  this has addition SharePoint specific data collected like Application ID, Site ID, Web ID, Correlation ID etc.

[SharePoint 2010 Usage and Health Service](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepoint_quick_reads/archive/2012/02/20/sharepoint-2010-usage-and-health-service.aspx)